# What is the probability of hitting the exact same spot on a dartboard two times in a row?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability of hitting the exact same spot on a dartboard two times in a row?
Is it 0?  Why?  What about the probability of hitting one spot on a dartboard, and hitting that exact spot again in the next ten throws?  Is it still zero?  What about hitting that spot again in your lifetime?  How about hitting that spot again once in an infinite amount of throws?

Comment: I would say the probabilities are related to the ratio of the area of the dart board and the area of the cross section of the spike on the dart.

Comment: "Buffon's Needle" could be loosely related to your question (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle ).

Comment: There is funny connection with continuum hypothesis and dartboard see this http://books.google.cz/books?id=qjVaD1OQbxEC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=continuum+hypothesis+dart+board&source=bl&ots=oyLwVgVwGL&sig=ZyiaC-eJ5xeysQDJI7U2RdSO7xk&hl=cs&sa=X&ei=s7REUtaAEPPb4QSzkICgBA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=continuum%20hypothesis%20dart%20board&f=false . Read the paragraph starting "This leads us to the stunning .."

Answer (score 4):

If by "the exact same spot" you mean a point, the chances are zero even with a countable infinity of throws, as there are uncountably many points.  Any countable set of points has no area.  If you mean within a small error, take the ratio of the area to the area of the dartboard (presumably you are assuming a uniform distribution over the dartboard and nowhere else) and that is the chance on the next throw.  Of course, those who can hit the dartboard every time don't have a uniform distribution of throws over it, so this is unrealistic.

Comment: Why does any countable set of points have no area?

Comment: [Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesbegue_measure) is countably additive.  If you add any countable collection of disjoint measurable sets, the total area is the total of the areas.  As each point has zero area, the total is still zero.